# Rxjs: shorthand of create observable from value or observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using `rxjs` with typescript. I wrote following two simple functions. But I guess `rxjs` already has such functionality. Does `rxjs`?

```
export function isObservable(value: any): value is Observable<any> {
  return value instanceof Observable;
}

export function createObservable<T>(value: T | Observable<T>): Observable < T > {
  return isObservable(value) ? value : Observable.of(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think RxJS 5 has exactly this functionality already because it's you who should be aware of what type of data you're working with.

However, you can make use of the fact that RxJS handles any Observables, Promises, Observable-like, array-like and so on ... objects the same way and write the following:

```
const val1 = Observable.of(42);
const val2 = [42];

Observable.from(val1).subscribe(console.log);
Observable.from(val2).subscribe(console.log);
```

This will in both cases print just `42` even though once I used an Observable with a single value and then an array with a single value.

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/fubobon/3/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1):

No it doesn't, probably because it's not very useful. Which use cases would you need it for?